# Material-UI v1.0.0.-beta Issue with React-Transition-Group

Tags: material-ui, react-transition-group

While testing `material-ui v1.0.0-beta`, I encountered with the following error when building using `webpack 3.8.0`. I came across with few other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592444/material-ui-bug-with-react-transition-group-v-2-2-0), too, but am hoping if someone could confirm this is a legitimate issue and is still seen by people? I even added `"react-transition-group": "^2.2.1"` to `package.json` and so far no luck. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/material-ui-next/ButtonBase/Ripple.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-transition-group/Transition' in './node_modules/material-ui-next/ButtonBase'
```

I have `"react-router": "^3.2.0",` in my `package.json` in case this may help folks understand what might be the root cause.

**[UPDATE]** While investigating, I removed `node_modules` and issued `npm cache clean` as well as ensure the global cache is cleared by issuing `npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' | xargs npm -g rm`. This didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps explained in this ticket for solution: [material-ui-next/9356](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9356)

**Summary of Solution**
The issue relates to how `webpack` searches for dependencies at build time and establishes the dependency graph of all peer dependencies for each and every module. When digging further, I noted that `material-ui@0.19.4` has `react-transition-group@1.2.1` as its peer dependency while `material-ui-next@1.0.0 beta` has `react-transition-group@2.2.1` as its peer dependency. Furthermore, I suspect because I have both `material-ui` releases on my project, when importing a component from `material-ui-next`, the expected path for `react-transition-group@2.2.1` from `material-ui-next`'s perspective is `project/node_modules` but apparently due to having two versions of `material-ui`, the later installs `react-transition-group@2.2.1` under `material-ui-next`.

In `webpack` path configurations, add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  app: path.resolve(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, "app"),
  assets: path.resolve(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, "public", "assets"),
  compiled: path.resolve(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, "compiled"),
  public: "/assets/",
  modules: path.resolve(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, "node_modules"),
  extraModules: path.resolve(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, 
  "node_modules/material-ui-next/node_modules"),
};
```

And finally add the extra path to `webpack`'s `resolve` attribute:

```
module.exports = {
  modules: [PATHS.app, PATHS.modules, PATHS.extraModules],
  extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css"],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

to fix above issue:

please install react-transition-group

> npm i react-transition-group@next --save